# server sends spam

Tags: postfix

Using: Ubuntu 14.04 lts, postfix 2.11
[After recieving many spam mails, I installed BitDefender FRAMS which workes fine for incoming spams. Since then noticed that the Software scans by far more mails then I send. Mail.log revealed that Spams are sent by my server using my domains. My hoster wrote my shortly later that I should kindly stop spamming. I switched postfix off now to not end up on blackhole lists.
This is a sample spam:

```
Return-Path: <6558998579.332d7edd@bounces.spamcop.net>
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1] helo=mail.hetzner.company) by mail.hetzner.company with esmtp (Exim 4.80) (envelope-from <6558998579.332d7edd@bounces.spamcop.net>) id 1bujQt-0005Ni-Kw for blacklist-abuse@hetzner.de; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 19:04:39 +0200
Received: from vmail by mail.hetzner.company with local (Exim 4.80) (envelope-from <6558998579.332d7edd@bounces.spamcop.net>) id 1bujQt-0005Nc-JS for blacklist-abuse@hetzner.de; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 19:04:39 +0200
Received: from [184.94.240.112] (helo=vmx.spamcop.net) by mail.hetzner.company with esmtp (Exim 4.80) (envelope-from <6558998579.332d7edd@bounces.spamcop.net>) id 1bujQp-0005M6-7j for abuse@hetzner.de; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 19:04:39 +0200
Received: from prod-sc-www02.sv4.ironport.com (HELO prod-sc-www02.spamcop.net) ([10.8.129.226]) by prod-sc-smtp-vip.sv4.ironport.com with SMTP; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 10:02:41 -0700
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 16:11:48 +0200
From: akys <6558998579@reports.spamcop.net>
To: abuse@hetzner.de
Message-ID: 1bujQt-0005Ni-Kw@mail.hetzner.company
Subject: [SpamCop
 (http://sitzungspause.de/ajax.php?d=78&JAd2AN6Pngk1GkL=5yu1&Dtf=GkR&3DHR=6x)
 id:6558998579]We offer new vacancy
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Envelope-to: blacklist-abuse@hetzner.de
Delivery-date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 19:04:39 +0200
X-Sieve: Pigeonhole Sieve 0.4.2
X-Sieve-Redirected-From: abuse-queue@hetzner.de
Precedence: list
X-SpamCop-sourceip: 136.243.54.13
X-Mailer: https://www.spamcop.net/ v4.8.5
Delivered-To: vmail-blacklist-abuse@hetzner.de

[ SpamCop V4.8.5 ]
This message is brief for your comfort.  Please use links below for details.

Email from 136.243.54.13 / Thu, 13 Oct 2016 16:11:48 +0200
https://www.spamcop.net/w3m?i=z6558998578z598b23159c6d840cca297b6681088a24z

Spamvertised web site: http://sitzungspause.de/ajax.php?d=78&JAd2AN6Pngk1GkL=5yu1&Dtf=GkR&3DHR=6x
https://www.spamcop.net/w3m?i=z6558998579z332d7edd03b56aea816c086bfac24f25z
http://sitzungspause.de/ajax.php?d=78&JAd2AN6Pngk1GkL=5yu1&Dtf=GkR&3DHR=6x is 136.243.54.13; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 17:02:38 GMT

[ Offending message ]
Received: from [80.67.29.35] (helo=mx02.ispgateway.de)
    by clara.ispgateway.de with esmtp (Exim 4.68)
    (envelope-from <benjamin_bond@sitzungspause.de>)
    id 1bugjd-0003Ui-It; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 16:11:49 +0200
Return-path: <benjamin_bond@sitzungspause.de>
X-Envelope-To: x
Received: from [136.243.54.13] (helo=hetzner.marketstrategy.de)
    by mx02.ispgateway.de with esmtps (TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256)
    (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <benjamin_bond@sitzungspause.de>)
    id 1bugjc-0008Pe-6Z
    for x; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 16:11:48 +0200
Received: by hetzner.marketstrategy.de (Postfix, from userid 33)
    id D278C4659DD; Thu, 13 Oct 2016 01:21:22 +0200 (CEST)
To: x
Subject: We offer new vacancy
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 33:footer.php(1949) : eval()'d code
Date: Thu, 13 Oct 2016 01:21:22 +0200
From: Benjamin Bond <benjamin_bond@sitzungspause.de>
Message-ID: <78e1________________________040f@sitzungspause.de>
X-Priority: 3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_78e1938deb0e56d06dc10debcd14040f"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on
    spamfilter03.ispgateway.de
X-Spam-Level: **********
X-Spam-Status: No, hits=10.0 required=9999.0 tests=BAYES_50,CMAE_1 autolearn=disabled
    version=3.3.1
X-Spam-CMAETAG: v=2.1 cv=SOLMVYfH c=1 sm=0 tr=0 p=T1AfiPlp5_8A:10
    p=ejwB5mvGAAAA:8 p=ViDQD3QmnzRg37tNSFIA:9 p=5CMhQTHRoVkA:10
    a=NR5p24IsT9jitHzPR8GR1Q==:17 a=1oJP67jkp3AA:10 a=CH0kA5CcgfcA:10
    a=ZZnuYtJkoWoA:10 a=nM72dFt57HW-7m5ojdUA:9 a=CjuIK1q_8ugA:10
    a=WYaTX5_29T0A:10 a=r6aDHOKj4ZoA:10 a=-FEs8UIgK8oA:10 a=NWVoK91CQyQA:10
    a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=tFiXSOtoEsEA:10 a=DB5G64JNwGM0eoeKYBz7:22
    xcat=Undefined/Undefined
X-Spam-CMAECATEGORY: 0
X-Spam-CMAESUBCATEGORY: 0
X-Spam-CMAESCORE: 100

--b1_78e1938deb0e56d06dc10debcd14040f
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

People like you and I have been wrong way too many times...
We've lost tones of money on stupid investments....
That's why I'm glad to inform you... I found what we've been looking for!

[ http://sitzungspause.de/ajax.php?d=78&JAd2AN6Pngk1GkL=5yu1&Dtf=GkR&3DHR=6x ] 100% free and it actually works


--b1_78e1938deb0e56d06dc10debcd14040f
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii

<html>
<body>
People like you and I have been wrong way too many times...<br>
We've lost tones of money on stupid investments....<br>
That's why I'm glad to inform you... I found what we've been looking for!<br>
<br>
<a href="http://sitzungspause.de/ajax.php?d=78&JAd2AN6Pngk1GkL=5yu1&Dtf=GkR&3DHR=6x">100% free and it actually works</a><br>
</body>
</html>

--b1_78e1938deb0e56d06dc10debcd14040f--
```

a sample from mail.log:

```
Oct 13 18:21:20 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4112]: E2D8F474FE6: message-id=<682a0ff1fae620bc32b430f32063c8ee@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:20 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: E2D8F474FE6: from=<loretta@sitzungspause.de>, size=1397, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:20 hetzner postfix/pickup[4067]: F1CF9474FF1: uid=33 from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:20 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4064]: F1CF9474FF1: message-id=<339053b3730de8fcb4917b174cfa1224@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/error[3878]: E2D8F474FE6: to=<allybally911@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.18, delays=0.09/0/0/0.1, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72] while sending RCPT TO)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: F1CF9474FF1: from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, size=1369, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/pickup[4067]: 156C2474FF4: uid=33 from=<loretta@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4058]: 156C2474FF4: message-id=<f953e8ef79a26fd783f357d75495605e@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[3939]: D3D8A473B9F: to=<ohiohornhunter@me.com>, relay=mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.133.229.11]:25, delay=2.4, delays=0.13/0/1.2/1.1, dsn=2.5.0, status=sent (250 2.5.0 Ok.)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: D3D8A473B9F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/error[3883]: F1CF9474FF1: to=<bosshog7964@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=0.27, delays=0.11/0/0/0.16, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36] while sending RCPT TO)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2784]: BC386474FB9: to=<kipwkroeger@verizon.net>, relay=relay.verizon.net[206.46.232.11]:25, delay=0.34, delays=0.07/0/0.27/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host relay.verizon.net[206.46.232.11] refused to talk to me: 571 Email from 136.243.54.13 is currently blocked by Verizon Online's anti-spam system. The email sender or Email Service Provider may visit http://www.verizon.net/whitelist and request removal of the block. 161013)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2741]: 787554742A0: to=<robinallison@optonline.net>, relay=mx.optimum.net[167.206.4.79]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.11/0/1.1/0.41, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.optimum.net[167.206.4.79] said: 554 5.7.1 Spam detected by content scanner.  Message rejected.  (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2742]: 6CDD84742C3: to=<johnny.ringo2121@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.27]:25, delay=0.68, delays=0.09/0/0.17/0.42, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [136.243.54.13] The IP address sending this message does not have a 550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from 550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.1 information. je6si1541506wjb.41 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 156C2474FF4: from=<loretta@sitzungspause.de>, size=1382, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/pickup[4067]: 3D9BF473B9F: uid=33 from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4112]: 3D9BF473B9F: message-id=<cc984f7be463c71cd621d33903743ef9@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4064]: 3DF18474FF6: message-id=<20161013162121.3DF18474FF6@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4061]: 3DF7E475080: message-id=<20161013162121.3DF7E475080@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: connect from webmail.esa.at[185.16.113.2]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/error[3880]: 156C2474FF4: to=<crosserjackie@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=0.27, delays=0.19/0/0/0.07, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.36] while sending RCPT TO)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/bounce[4048]: 6CDD84742C3: sender non-delivery notification: 3DF18474FF6
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/bounce[4052]: 787554742A0: sender non-delivery notification: 3DF7E475080
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3D9BF473B9F: from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, size=1333, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/pickup[4067]: 5043E475051: uid=33 from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 6CDD84742C3: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 787554742A0: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3DF7E475080: from=<>, size=3431, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4058]: 5043E475051: message-id=<578305bb9376b96a497402f8cf048959@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3DF18474FF6: from=<>, size=4095, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 5043E475051: from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, size=1396, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2754]: 7C412474F7F: to=<flickerst@charter.net>, relay=mx1.charter.net[68.114.188.69]:25, delay=0.83, delays=0.09/0/0.32/0.42, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 v4ML1t02v0H6Qkw014MLSN mail accepted for delivery E0000)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 7C412474F7F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2783]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c02::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3651]: connect from mx.ab.pl[195.116.103.72]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2828]: 3DF7E475080: to=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for sitzungspause.de loops back to myself)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2740]: 3DF18474FF6: to=<loretta@sitzungspause.de>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for sitzungspause.de loops back to myself)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/error[3879]: 5043E475051: to=<jldevane1@hotmail.com>, relay=none, delay=0.1, delays=0.01/0/0/0.09, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.72] while sending RCPT TO)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3DF7E475080: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3DF18474FF6: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/pickup[4067]: 66D844742A0: uid=33 from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4061]: 66D844742A0: message-id=<a411dca2cc8b9eb4329557594ef1ce27@sitzungspause.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from webmail.esa.at[185.16.113.2]: 454 4.7.1 <jayden_bowers@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<jayden_bowers@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<webmail.esa.at>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: disconnect from webmail.esa.at[185.16.113.2]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3651]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mx.ab.pl[195.116.103.72]: 454 4.7.1 <monika_szymanski@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<monika_szymanski@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mx.ab.pl>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 66D844742A0: from=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, size=1315, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2974]: connect to mx2.comcast.net[2001:558:fe21:2a::6]:25: Network is unreachable
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2905]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2905]: 846B64742C3: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3651]: disconnect from mx.ab.pl[195.116.103.72]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4064]: 846B64742C3: message-id=<20161013162121.846B64742C3@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: 846B64742C3: no signing table match for 'bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de'
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: 846B64742C3: no signature data
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 846B64742C3: from=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, size=731, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2905]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3139]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: 991EB474F7F: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3139]: A2B9D474FF6: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4112]: 991EB474F7F: message-id=<20161013162121.991EB474F7F@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: 991EB474F7F: no signing table match for 'bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de'
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: 991EB474F7F: no signature data
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 991EB474F7F: from=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, size=731, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3122]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3122]: B71AB47505E: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4061]: A2B9D474FF6: message-id=<20161013162121.846B64742C3@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: A2B9D474FF6: no signing table match for 'bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de'
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: A2B9D474FF6: no signature data
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2784]: 846B64742C3: to=<postmaster@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10025, delay=0.29, delays=0.08/0/0.04/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A2B9D474FF6)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: A2B9D474FF6: from=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, size=1635, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3139]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 846B64742C3: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2783]: 3D9BF473B9F: to=<thomaskedwards@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.27]:25, delay=0.64, delays=0.18/0/0.16/0.3, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.71.27] said: 550-5.7.1 [136.243.54.13] The IP address sending this message does not have a 550-5.7.1 PTR record setup. As a policy, Gmail does not accept messages from 550-5.7.1 IPs with missing PTR records. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550 5.7.1 information. cj2si18572616wjc.184 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4058]: D4A34475080: message-id=<20161013162121.D4A34475080@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2752]: 3DF0947427A: to=<rgetche@comcast.net>, relay=mx1.comcast.net[96.114.157.80]:25, delay=2.7, delays=0.11/0/1.6/0.97, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 v4MK1t04n0H6Qkw014MM3R mail accepted for delivery)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[3939]: A2B9D474FF6: to=<postmaster@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=none, delay=0.17, delays=0.17/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hetzner.marketstrategy.de type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4112]: DD5334750B3: message-id=<20161013162121.DD5334750B3@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4064]: B71AB47505E: message-id=<20161013162121.991EB474F7F@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: B71AB47505E: no signing table match for 'bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de'
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner opendkim[2519]: B71AB47505E: no signature data
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/bounce[4063]: 3D9BF473B9F: sender non-delivery notification: D4A34475080
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: D4A34475080: from=<>, size=4056, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3D9BF473B9F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: DD5334750B3: from=<>, size=3799, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: B71AB47505E: from=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, size=1635, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/bounce[4117]: A2B9D474FF6: sender non-delivery notification: DD5334750B3
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtp[2977]: 991EB474F7F: to=<postmaster@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10025, delay=0.36, delays=0.08/0/0.04/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as B71AB47505E)
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3122]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 991EB474F7F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:21 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: A2B9D474FF6: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2754]: B71AB47505E: to=<postmaster@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=none, delay=0.21, delays=0.2/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hetzner.marketstrategy.de type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2735]: D4A34475080: to=<becky@sitzungspause.de>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for sitzungspause.de loops back to myself)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2828]: DD5334750B3: to=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hetzner.marketstrategy.de type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: D4A34475080: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: DD5334750B3: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4061]: 07275473B9F: message-id=<20161013162122.07275473B9F@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2975]: 90A1A474FA1: to=<fpdenke@optonline.net>, relay=mx.optimum.net[167.206.4.77]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.09/0/0.93/0.39, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx.optimum.net[167.206.4.77] said: 554 5.7.1 Spam detected by content scanner.  Message rejected.  (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/cleanup[4058]: 10AA7474F7F: message-id=<20161013162122.10AA7474F7F@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 3DF0947427A: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/bounce[4063]: B71AB47505E: sender non-delivery notification: 07275473B9F
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 10AA7474F7F: from=<>, size=3483, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: B71AB47505E: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 07275473B9F: from=<>, size=3799, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/bounce[4258]: 90A1A474FA1: sender non-delivery notification: 10AA7474F7F
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 90A1A474FA1: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2747]: 10AA7474F7F: to=<loretta@sitzungspause.de>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.04/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for sitzungspause.de loops back to myself)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2827]: 07275473B9F: to=<bitdefender@hetzner.marketstrategy.de>, relay=none, delay=0.08, delays=0.08/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=hetzner.marketstrategy.de type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 10AA7474F7F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 07275473B9F: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtp[2768]: A3784474FAA: to=<chuckl331@comcast.net>, relay=mx2.comcast.net[68.87.20.5]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.11/0/0.93/0.54, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 v4ML1t0620H6Qkw014MMdV mail accepted for delivery)
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: A3784474FAA: removed
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: connect from mail.coma.de[62.245.168.42]
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.coma.de[62.245.168.42]: 454 4.7.1 <gisela_rolf@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<gisela_rolf@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.coma.de>
Oct 13 18:21:22 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: disconnect from mail.coma.de[62.245.168.42]
Oct 13 18:21:24 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3575]: connect from smtp-33-i6.italiaonline.it[212.48.14.167]
Oct 13 18:21:24 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3575]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from smtp-33-i6.italiaonline.it[212.48.14.167]: 454 4.7.1 <ethan_cummings@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<ethan_cummings@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<libero.it>
Oct 13 18:21:24 hetzner postfix/smtp[2767]: CC5B8474FCE: to=<seyayukikohayashi@yahoo.co.jp>, relay=mx3.mail.yahoo.co.jp[182.22.12.249]:25, delay=3.7, delays=0.1/0/1.1/2.6, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Oct 13 18:21:24 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: CC5B8474FCE: removed
Oct 13 18:21:25 hetzner postfix/smtp[2974]: 66D844742A0: to=<glenyo2@comcast.net>, relay=mx1.comcast.net[96.114.157.80]:25, delay=4.1, delays=0.11/0/2.8/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 v4MN1t06J0H6Qkw014MQ8T mail accepted for delivery)
Oct 13 18:21:25 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3651]: connect from piast.pertus.com.pl[195.116.191.6]
Oct 13 18:21:25 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 66D844742A0: removed
Oct 13 18:21:25 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3651]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from piast.pertus.com.pl[195.116.191.6]: 454 4.7.1 <adam_wisniewski@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<adam_wisniewski@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<piast.pertus.com.pl>
Oct 13 18:21:26 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: connect from mail.tgacademy.org.uk[82.45.159.13]
Oct 13 18:21:26 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.tgacademy.org.uk[82.45.159.13]: 454 4.7.1 <justin_fields@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<justin_fields@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.tgacademy.org.uk>
Oct 13 18:21:26 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail.tgacademy.org.uk[82.45.159.13]: 454 4.7.1 <justin_fields@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<justin_fields@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.tgacademy.org.uk>
Oct 13 18:21:26 hetzner postfix/smtpd[2778]: disconnect from mail.tgacademy.org.uk[82.45.159.13]
Oct 13 18:21:28 hetzner postfix/smtp[2903]: AD3F84763A9: to=<dre@wangfu.ca>, relay=smtp-2.storm.ca[209.87.239.68]:25, delay=134110, delays=134054/0/1.2/55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as DD95F840184)
Oct 13 18:21:28 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: AD3F84763A9: removed
Oct 13 18:21:29 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: connect from kermit.polishtravel.com.pl[46.28.243.13]
Oct 13 18:21:29 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from kermit.polishtravel.com.pl[46.28.243.13]: 454 4.7.1 <jadwiga_zielinski@sitzungspause.de>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<jadwiga_zielinski@sitzungspause.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<kermit.polishtravel.com.pl>
Oct 13 18:21:29 hetzner postfix/smtpd[3628]: disconnect from kermit.polishtravel.com.pl[46.28.243.13]
Oct 13 18:21:29 hetzner postfix/smtp[2737]: 16D8C474F6B: to=<readcoin@telusplanet.net>, relay=mx.telus.net[207.167.198.25]:25, delay=9.3, delays=0.14/0/5.2/3.9, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 uikybUTZMmDGquil3b84rg mail accepted for delivery)
Oct 13 18:21:29 hetzner postfix/qmgr[2658]: 16D8C474F6B: removed
```

@sitzungpause.de is a domain of my server which sends spam (alltough it isn't meant to be a mail domain)
I run ClamAV and installed DKI and SPF (which works) but I'm slowly running out of ideas what to do next...

Which information do you need also?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @fkraiem It would be helpful if comments on this site stuck to a constructive tone. We were all noobs once, and non-constructive criticism doesn't help anyone learn. What resources would you suggest for Luggie to learn how to properly manage a mailserver?

Comment: @fkraiem I respect your view and stand by mine. While I don't want this discussion to become too prolonged, it sounds like fkraiem is genuinely trying to become a better mailserver admin. In addition to recommending that they shut down their server, what resources would you recommend for someone who wants to learn how to manage a mailserver properly?

Comment: I heard the same conversations in other forums as well.... In order to learn I need advice and thats why I'm asking questions. Some forums seem to be there for people who already know everything. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Postfix is a beast to configure, you must ensure `/etc/postfix/master.cf` and `/etc/postfix/main.cf` are well-configured.

But since it's painful, I suggest you install a front end by following a tutorial. I had big success with [ispconfig3](http://ispcponfig.org) on low-end VPS.  You can find Ubuntu 14.04 tutorial [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-apache2-php-mysql-pureftpd-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3).  You can skip some parts about unwanted features like bind, and ftp daemon.

good luck !

Comment: I'll do that. Since my mail server is already infected,  it would be best to reinstall it (the entire server?) I guess?

Comment: @LuggieBöörgöör Probably your server is not infected but postfix is wide open so it's easy to send mails without any requirement.  But if reinstall doesn't hurt you, go for it !